# Multiple applications in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have many node.js applications (created by different people) running on different ports in a single server. I want to run all those seperate application in a single node.js server.

I am new to Node.js. I have worked on web development tools like web2py before. In web2py we can create multiple applications in a single server.

Is there any framework in node.js which will help to create multiple applications in a single node.js server.

I have tried to create multiple applications like this

```
app.use('/app1', express.Router()); 
app.use('/app2', express.Router()); 
var app1 = require("./applications/app1/server_code.js");
var app1_inst = new app1(express.Router());
```

It is working, but the problem is, I have to change all the internal application url to "**/app1**/url".

Is there any other easy way to do that.

Comment: If all the apps do not need to be in the same baseurl, just create different nginx server blocks. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: http://shamadeh.com/blog/web/nodejs/express/2014/07/20/ExpressMultipleSites.html